# Creating a Video from Pano2VR results in corrupted frames

Tags: ffmpeg, animation, animation-rendering

Has anyone been able to use Pano2VR Pro to generate videos of their tours using the Animation Output option? Pano2VR uses ffmpeg to generate video frames.
I have attempted to use this feature numerous times over the years and always get bad results. The video frames it generates for the video has bits and pieces of 2-3 photos overlapped in the frame. I am attaching a sample.
[image]
This has happen on 3 different computers so I am fairly confident it isn't hardware related. I can create html type tours with no problem. It only happens if I try to create a set of images to make a video. It happens if I enable the Generate Video File or leave it disabled. Note that I have the ffmpeg installed.
In this screenshot of the Pano2VR screen, the photo that I am using to attempt to create the video from is a 2.85 Giga-pixel (37,788 x 75,576 pixels) image.
[image: screenshot]
Currently i am using Pano2VR on a Windows 11 OS to create virtual tours of my Gigapixel photography.  I am running a 13th Generation Raptor Lake Intel(R) Core(TM) i9-13900K 24 Core, 32 thread CPU, ASUS ProART Z790 Creator Motherboard is populated with 128 Gigabytes of DDR5 memory,  ASUS GEFORCE RTX 4070 Ti GPU video card.

Any suggestions anyone might have would be most appreciated. I would really like to be able to create videos from Pan02VR.

Comment: Without `Generate Video File`, does it create an image sequence? If so, view the images externally and check whether they look ok.

Comment: Yes, it creates an image sequence with Generate Video File turned OFF. The corrupted image file happens regardless of if I enable the Generate Video File or leave it disabled. The first image on my initial post is one of the created images.

Comment: That sounds like a Pano2VR issue as ffmpeg is only used for the `Generate Video File` option.